# Netflix interferes with Safari custom tab change shortcut?

Tags: safari, video, shortcut

I used [this](https://medium.com/@standingdreams/changing-safari-keyboard-shortcut-to-change-tabs-or-any-mac-application-e06730faead2) method to set the tab-changing shortcut in Safari to Cmd+Opt+Left/Right (same as in Chrome). It works, except that when I'm watching Netflix and try changing tabs while the video is playing, it registers only as left/right and makes the video jump backward/forward by 10 seconds, instead of changing tabs as intended.

Is there a way to fix this? I would like Cmd+Opt+Left/Right to always change tabs, even if the webpage I'm on has specific behavior for the left/right keys on their own.

Strangely, Youtube does not have this issue, even though the left/right keys have similar behavior for the Youtube video player.

Answer (score 2):

Using [hammerspoon](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon). After installing hammerspoon (I used `brew cask install hammerspoon`), just edit/create the file `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` to include:

```lua
left = hs.hotkey.new({"cmd", "alt"}, "left", function()
  hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd", "shift"}, "[")
end)

right = hs.hotkey.new({"cmd", "alt"}, "right", function()
  hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd", "shift"}, "]")
end)

hs.application.watcher.new(function(appName, eventType, appObject)
  if appName == "Safari" then
    if eventType == hs.application.watcher.activated then
      left:enable()
      right:enable()
    elseif eventType == hs.application.watcher.deactivated then
      left:disable()
      right:disable()
    end
  end
end):start()
```

Then start Hammerspoon.app.

Then enable Hammerspoon control in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility. (Maybe you will need to Reload Config from Hammerspoon's menu bar item after this).

Comment: I wish I used any of these more. Thank you so much for the answers. I’m not even sure this Safari question is on Mac, looking at the question. Great answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org), you can remap cmd-alt-arrow to the Safari equivalent. I have tested, and confirmed this solves your Netflix problem.

I used `brew cask install karabiner-elements` to install Karabiner Elements. You can also use the installer from [their website](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org).

You need to make a new complex modification in Karabiner-Elements with these contents:

```json
{
  "title": "Custom Safari Tab Navigation",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Use Chrome keyboard shortcuts in Safari.",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "left_arrow",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [ "command", "option" ]
            }
          },
          "to": [{
            "key_code": "open_bracket",
            "modifiers": [ "command", "shift" ]
          }],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Safari$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "right_arrow",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command",
                "option"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [{
            "key_code": "close_bracket",
            "modifiers": [ "command", "shift" ]
          }],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Safari$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Complex modifications are stored in JSON files in ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications.

You could copy the above into your clipboard, then

```
pbpaste > ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/chromelike_change_tab.json
```

Or go about adding a JSON file inside of that folder with these contents yourself.

Then inside of Karabiner-Elements.app you can navigate to Complex modifications using the bar at the top, click Add Rule in the bottom-left, then enable the "Use Chrome keyboard shortcuts in Safari" rule.

Answer (score 1):

Using a userscript:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        NewScript-k5v43
// @description This is your new userscript, start writing code
// @match       https://www.netflix.com/watch/*
// ==/UserScript==

function ignoreChromeTabChange(event) {
  const left = 37;
  const right = 39;
  if ([left, right].includes(event.keyCode)
    && event.getModifierState('Meta') // Meta is CMD
    && event.getModifierState('Alt')) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
};

window.addEventListener('keydown', ignoreChromeTabChange, true);
```

You'll have to have a userscript manager, and the go-to Tampermonkey costs money for Safari now.

I tested using the free open source app [userscripts](https://github.com/quoid/userscripts). I guess you could use it too if you don't yet have a preferred userscript manager.